# Unable to rotate views using Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developping an App using Xcode 4.2 , I am using Storyboard

I am trying to make the App rotatable , but it doesn t rotate , here is the code I am using :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown|| interfaceOrientation !=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

and in the project information , I have all the orientations supported ....

am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned you have all orientation supported. But just to mkae sure, in the project info page, can you check the property "Supported Interface Orientations" property and check if all orientations are there

Comment: "supported interface orientations" , type : array  , value :4 items (and the four of them are there)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support all orientations you should just return Yes there instead of what you, which will be Yes every time anyways. Is this your top level view controller? If you've embedded a view controller within another (which usually you shouldn't), than make sure the top most view controller has this method and it returns yes.

Comment: I tried to return YES , but still isn t working ... I have put yes in all the views and still nothing